# How do I properly add pagination using partial views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have this partial view that looks like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container-1">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="@item.ProductImage" />
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
            <p>@item.SubTitle</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-button">
            <p>@item.SKU</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-button">
            <p class="mt-3 mr-2">$@item.Price</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

And this is how I'm implementing it in my index.cshtml

```
<div id="itemsss">
    <partial name="_Item" />
</div>
```

Now in order to make sure that only the partial view updates dynamically without having to manually refresh the entire page I'm using ajax like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(CheckAvailability, 500);
});

function CheckAvailability() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Dashboard/CheckChange",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        mimeType: "text/html",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#itemsss').load("/Dashboard/ReturnItems");
                console.log("Updated!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed!");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Where the idea is that it will fetch the data every .5 seconds whether there has been a change or not, again just to keep it updates. It loads all the partial view divs into the div with the id of `itemsss` which you can see in the index.cshtml

And the action it's fetching would be this

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ReturnItems()
{
    Items = new List<EbayProduct>();
    using (var ctx = new UserContext())
    {
        Items = ctx.Users.Include(x => x.Items).Where(x => x.Username == "Admin").FirstOrDefault().Items;
    }
    return PartialView("_Item", Items);
}
```

And this works great, it keeps it updated and what not.

The issue is that it adds it all in one big list, where as I want to start using pagination once it hits 7 or more items in the collection. I honestly have no idea how to do that.
How would I properly implement pagination to something like this? I had bootstrap pagination in mind but I just don't see how I would do that.

Comment: but as you are saying, your function will call every 5 seconds, so if user is on second or third page, your ajax call display it first page again and again. so first change your continues calling functionality

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datatable is a good choice, you can follow the document to implement the pagination.

https://datatables.net/

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/